# How to use Rg.Plugins.Popup for a "SlideDrawer" popup page

Tags: xamarin.forms

The Rg.Plugins.Popup is a great plug in. We are trying to implement a SlideDrawer (a popup page that will slide from the Top and cover the screen from the top of the screen through the height of the popup).

How can we use Rg.Plugins.Popup with animation to achieve this?

Thanks,
Mano

Comment: How about the [**animations support from this plugin**](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Animations)? Have you tried it?

Comment: Take a look at [ViewExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.viewextensions?view=xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RgPlugin's animations with the RgPlugin's popup to achieve your desired functionality.

[https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Animations]

For example, in the case which you have mentioned, it could be like below,

```
<pages:PopupPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
x:Class="MyProject.MyPopupPage">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Top"
            PositionOut="Top"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="1.2"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="400"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <!--Your content of drawer-->
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Reference [Link](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/PopupPage)